# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'Glomindz Support'

Tags: java

I am not able to retrieve column values from my database table with the following coding a message has been displayed in the console:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'Glomindz Support'
```

My code is:

```
package com.glomindz.mercuri.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.glomindz.mercuri.util.MySingleTon;

public class UserServicesDAO {

    private Connection connection;

    public UserServicesDAO() {
        // connection = new MySingleTon().getConnection();
        connection = MySingleTon.getInstance().getConnection();

    }

    public void get_all_data() {
    }

    public Map<Integer, String> get_all_data1() {
        HashMap<Integer, String> result = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM spl_user_master";
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            boolean execute = stmt.execute();
            System.out.println(execute);
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
            System.out.println(resultSet.getMetaData());
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                result.put(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getString("id"));
                result.put(resultSet.getInt(2), resultSet.getString("name"));
                result.put(resultSet.getInt(3), resultSet.getString("email"));
                result.put(resultSet.getInt(4), resultSet.getString("mobile"));
                result.put(resultSet.getInt(5), resultSet.getString("password"));
                result.put(resultSet.getInt(6), resultSet.getString("role"));
                result.put(resultSet.getInt(7), resultSet.getString("status"));
                result.put(resultSet.getInt(8),
                        resultSet.getString("last_update"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new UserServicesDAO().get_all_data1();
    }
}
```

My db table schema is:

```
id  name    email   mobile  password    role    status  last_update
1   Glomindz Support    support@glomindz.com    9854087006  cbf91a71c11d5ec348b0c7e9b2f0055e    admin   1   2013-05-02 22:05:14
2   Amarjyoti Das   amarjyotidas@splcare.com    9864092598  88f2dccb02b2a20615211e5492f85204    admin   1   2013-04-26 05:44:41
```

Comment: can you share your db table schema

Comment: `getInt()` means that the value you get from the recordset is an int, which "Glomindz Support" (among others) is clearly not. It doesn't mean that it returns any type of value with an integer index. Same kind of remark for getString().

Answer (score 3):

You retrieve every column as an `int` for the key.  I assume that some of these columns represent `String`s or `Date`s.

```
while(resultSet.next()){
    result.put(resultSet.getInt(1),resultSet.getString("id"));
    result.put(resultSet.getInt(2),resultSet.getString("name")); //Most likely a String
    result.put(resultSet.getInt(3),resultSet.getString("email"));
    result.put(resultSet.getInt(4),resultSet.getString("mobile"));
    result.put(resultSet.getInt(5),resultSet.getString("password"));
    result.put(resultSet.getInt(6),resultSet.getString("role"));
    result.put(resultSet.getInt(7),resultSet.getString("status"));
    result.put(resultSet.getInt(8),resultSet.getString("last_update"));  //Most likely a date
}
```

The inconsistencies between the data types and the object/value returned by the `getInt()` method causes the error.  I would suggest building/modeling an object in your domain that stores rows from the table.  Something like:

```
public class User{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String mobile;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private String status;
    private Date lastUpdate;

    /*  Get and set methods for each field */
}
```

Then build a Map containing the object as the value and the `id` as the key:

```
   //Use Map interface here, also notice generic arguments <Integer,User>
   Map<Integer, User> result = new HashMap<Integer, User>();
   try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        boolean execute = stmt.execute();
        System.out.println(execute);
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
        System.out.println(resultSet.getMetaData());
        while(resultSet.next()){
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(resultSet.getString("name");
            user.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email");
            //do this for each field, using appropriate method for type...

            //then add to map
            result.put(user.getId(), user);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need all your data from the table as a Map. But you may have multiple rows in your DB, therefore you basically want a list of maps! Modify your method to something like this:-

```
public List<Map<Integer, String>> get_all_data1() {
    List<Map<Integer, String>> allRows = new ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM spl_user_master";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        boolean execute = stmt.execute();
        System.out.println(execute);
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
        System.out.println(resultSet.getMetaData());
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Map<Integer, String> result = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            result.put(1, resultSet.getString("id"));
            result.put(2, resultSet.getString("name"));
            result.put(3, resultSet.getString("email"));
            result.put(4, resultSet.getString("mobile"));
            result.put(5, resultSet.getString("password"));
            result.put(6, resultSet.getString("role"));
            result.put(7, resultSet.getString("status"));
            result.put(8, resultSet.getString("last_update"));
            allRows.add(result);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return allRows;
}
```

Here, for every fetched record from the DB, the columns are put into the `Map`, and each map, represents a row, which is added to a `List`!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JPA annotations to map entity fields with db table, you need to use `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` annotation on ENUM type entity fields.

Comment: I was getting Invalid value for getInt() due to this. this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to, while creating the table you may mentioned  `name` column as INTEGER. So while retrieving it will get that column using `getInt()` method. But actually the column is of type STRING.

U should change the datatype of `name` column to STRING and this issue will be fixed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, `getInt()` or `getString()` requires columnIndex or columnLabel to get value for that column in particular entry. To find the column index you need to use `findColumn(name)` method to get its columnIndex. So your code should be as follows:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
                result.put(resultSet.findColumn("id"), resultSet.getInt("id"));
                result.put(resultSet.findColumn("name"), resultSet.getString("name"));
                result.put(resultSet.findColumn("email"), resultSet.getString("email"));
                result.put(resultSet.findColumn("mobile"), resultSet.getInt("mobile"));
                result.put(resultSet.findColumn("password"), resultSet.getString("password"));
                result.put(resultSet.findColumn("role"), resultSet.getString("role"));
                result.put(resultSet.findColumn("status"), resultSet.getInt("status"));
                result.put(resultSet.findColumn("last_update"),
                        resultSet.getString("last_update"));
            }
```

Basically you need to get your values according to the datatype with which it had been saved in DB. Check available methods to retrieve values by Ctrl+Click on ResultSet class

Answer (score -1):

Please check the syntax error for a small mistake for comma(,) you are added before the select statement

Example:

```
select id, name, mobile, address from table_name;
```

but you are using like

```
select id, name, mobile, address, from table_name;
```

please check and correct it